# What implies that transverse EM fields satisfy Laplace's in TEM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, vector-fields, microwaves

I am reading Pozar's *Microwave engieering*. When explaining the TEM waves (pag98 4th edition) he defines $\bar{e}(x, y)$ as the transverse electric field. He proves that $$\nabla_{t}^{2} \bar{e}(x, y)=0$$
$$\nabla_{t}^{2} \bar{h}(x, y)=0$$

What I don't understand is the statement that follows, which is:

> The transverse fields of a TEM wave are thus the same as the static fields that can exist
> between the conductors.

What does it mean? In electrostatics I have always used the Laplace equation with the potential but never with the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\nabla_t \times \bar e = -\mathfrak j \omega \mu h_z$ and for TEM wave $h_z=0$ this $\bar e$ field is conservative, that is $\bar e(x,y) = \nabla_t \phi(x,y)$ and *this* $\phi$ is the same that you would get by solving the 2-dimensional electro-static problem of $\nabla_t^2 \phi = 0$ with $\phi|_{\partial B} = \Phi_k$ given on the $k^{th}$ metal boundary of the waveguide. The main take-away is that for a TEM line the potential difference ("voltage drop") defined by the integral $V(2,1)=\int_{k=1}^{k=2} \bar e \cdot d\bar {\ell}$ between the metal boundaries is well defined irrespective of the path taken as long as the path of integration is taken in the cross section $(x,y)$.

Comment: Very nice explanation, the only thing I still don't understand what $\nabla_{t}^{2} \bar{e}(x, y)=0$ has to do with that. All you have said derives only from $\nabla_{t} \times \bar{e}=-j \omega \mu h_{z}$?

Comment: In general you have $\nabla_t^2 \bar e +(k^2 -\beta^2)\bar e=0$ but for a TEM wave $\beta = k$ *and* also $h_z=e_z=0$ from which $\nabla_t  \times \bar e = 0$ follows. This is also true for all cutoff modes even in a inhomogeneous filled waveguide where no pure TE, TM or TEM *propagating* modes can exist.